# Relation between more than two tables or models on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this method:

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany("Tag","question_tags");
}
```

this get the Tag's details through the question_tags table and connects **Tag** with **Questions** like:

**Tags <- question_tags <- questions**

Now I need to get the tag's details but using this relations:

**Tag <- question_revision_tags <- question_revisions <- questions**

but I can't make it work with a belongsToMany() or hasManyThrough() because there are more than 2 models implicated.

you think, it would be better if I insert a column on `question_revision_tags` called question_id? or is there a way to make this relation?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can make models Tag, QuestionRevision  and Question.

I understand that right now you have "Question has many-to-many Tag-s" and it works fine.

Now you want to have

- Question has one-to-many QuestionRevisions
- QuestionRevisionTags has many-to-many Tag-s

After building such relationships you can get all tags of the question and all questions of a tag also. In this case there is no needfor 2 step many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I know what you mean, I already did that man, but I have a question, what would be the correct laravel query for this? maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: There is no more correct query for this. It is very rare situation and thus no extra feature is written for this situation.